# Generalized Pauli matrix for spin larger than 1/2

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, group-theory, lie-algebra, representation-theory

for Spin 1/2, we have Pauli matrix as in [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices). So what's the generalized 3-by-3 Pauli matrix for spin 1 or even larger spin? Is there a generalization method?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79348/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Searching for "spin 1 matrices" yields a plethora of usable results. This question shows no research effort.

Answer (score 1):

The spin operator (or Pauli matrices ) is in general the **angular momentum operator** $J_{x}, \, J_{y}, \, J_{z}$ in which they satisfy the commutation relation
\begin{align*}
[J_{i} , \, J_{j}] = i \hbar \epsilon_{ijk} J_{k} \quad \mathrm{and} \quad [J^2 , \, J_{i}] = 0
\end{align*}
and they operate on the state as
\begin{align*}
J^2 | j, m>  \quad &=  \quad  j(j+1) \hbar^2 \; |j,m> \\
J_{\pm} |j , m > \quad &= \quad \hbar \sqrt{j(j+1) \mp m( m \pm 1)} \; |j,m \pm 1>
\end{align*}
where $J_{\pm } = J_{x} \pm i J_{y} $. $ j $ is the angular momentum quantum number and $m$ is the z-direction (usually) angular momentum quantum number. Note that $j$ can be positive integer (and zero) or half-integer and $ m = -j , \, -j+1 , \, \cdots , j-1 , \, j$

For the case of spin $1/2$, we put $j = 1/2$  and the allowed $m = -1/2$ and $1/2$. Then apply the rules above to obtain the matrix elements for the spin (or angular momentum) operator