# If an $SU (2)$ isospin transformation converts a proton to a neutron, how does a pion transform under the same transformation?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, group-theory, representation-theory, isospin-symmetry

I read in a particle physics note that if an $SU(2)$ isospin transformation makes $p\rightarrow n$ then under the same transformation pions go like $\pi^+ \rightarrow\pi^-$. I'm assuming that this means $\pi^0$ remains unchanged under this transformation.

Now if I represent $p$ to be $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\
0 \end{pmatrix}$

And $n$ to be $\begin{pmatrix} 0\\
1\end{pmatrix}$

The $SU (2)$ element with a two dimensional representation $\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\
1&0\end{pmatrix}$ is the required transformation.

But pions are isospin triplet hence we need the representations

$\pi^+ = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\
0\end{pmatrix}$

$\pi^0 = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\\
0\end{pmatrix}$

$\pi^- = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\
1\end{pmatrix}$

Now I (vaguely) understand that $SU(2)$ can have a three-dimensional representation. But the matrix representation of the element that makes these transformations is as follows

$\begin{pmatrix} 0&0&1\\
0&1&0\\
1&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$

This is indeed unitary, but how do I know that this is a representation of an $SU(2)$ element?
How can I construct the above matrix from the three dimensional generators of $SU(2)$?

Comment: Are you talking about an $S_1$ SU(2) transformation, perhaps?

Comment: I dont have deep understanding in representations but I understand the answer given to this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2192159/how-can-su2-group-has-3-dimensional-representation#:~:text=To%20construct%20the%20n%2Ddimensional,%2CJy%2CJz.

Comment: Nonono... That entry has the wrong basis, the way you have derived the states. [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/279880/is-the-adjoint-representation-of-su2-the-same-as-the-triplet-representation) is in your basis. Are you familiar with the Rodrigues rotation [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula#Matrix_notation)? You need to rotate by π around the y-axis....

Comment: Related : [What is the symmetry of the pion triplet (π−,π0,π+)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/420080/what-is-the-symmetry-of-the-pion-triplet-pi-pi0-pi).

Answer (score 0):

There is a geometrical interpretation of this fact. You need to look at the adjoint action of the group $SU(2)$ on its Lie algebra representing isospin. This can be identified by the rotation group $SO(3)$.

You want to send $p\to n$, which amounts to flipping the sign of $I_3$. You cannot do this by leaving the other components unchanged, you need to change them as well. Geometrically, you are looking for a rotation that flips the sign of the $z$ axis. One possible candidate os the $\pi$ rotation about the $y$ axis. Any other rotation can obtained by adding a rotation about the $z$ axis.

This immediately gives you the result, if the rotation switches $p\to n$ then it switches $\pi^+\to\pi^-$ leaving $\pi^0$ unchanged up to possible phase changes.

Explicitly, in matrix notation this is tabulated by the Wigner $d$ matrices (hence the choice of the $y$ axis). This gives in the fundamental representation $p,n$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

up to a multiplication of:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
e^{i\phi/2} & 0\\
0 & e^{-i\phi/2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Btw your matrix was not even in $SU(2)$.

And in the adjoint representation $\pi^{+,0,-}$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

up to a multiplication by:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
e^{i\phi} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & e^{-i\phi}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Btw the result is more natural in the $x,y,z$ basis in which case you get:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Up to a multiplication by:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\phi & -\sin\phi& 0\\
\sin\phi & \cos\phi & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Hope this helps.